# In sbt, how do you override scalacOptions for console in all configurations?

Tags: scala, sbt

I like defining `scalacOptions` at the top level like so (as an example, ignoring project axis for now):

```
scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-unused-import"
```

But then I realised that's too strict for `console`. So I tried setting:

```
scalacOptions in console ~= (_ filterNot (_ == "-Ywarn-unused-import"))
```

But that didn't work (still got (fatal) warnings in the REPL).

I used `inspect` to try and understand why:

```
> inspect console
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Starts the Scala interpreter with the project classes on the classpath.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/a/}b/compile:console
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:261
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:console::compilers
[info]  compile:console::initialCommands
[info]  compile:console::fullClasspath
[info]  compile:console::taskTemporaryDirectory
[info]  compile:console::scalaInstance
[info]  compile:console::streams
[info]  compile:console::cleanupCommands
[info]  compile:console::scalacOptions
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:console
[info]  *:console
[info]  {.}/compile:console
[info]  {.}/*:console
[info]  */compile:console
[info]  */*:console
[info] Related:
[info]  test:console
```

Note: `console` is

- provided by `compile:console`
- depends on `compile:console::scalacOptions`

then:

```
> inspect compile:console::scalacOptions
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]
[info] Description:
[info]  Options for the Scala compiler.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/a/}b/compile:scalacOptions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:1593
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:console
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:console::scalacOptions
[info]  compile:scalacOptions
[info]  *:console::scalacOptions
[info]  *:scalacOptions
[info]  {.}/compile:console::scalacOptions
[info]  {.}/compile:scalacOptions
[info]  {.}/*:console::scalacOptions
[info]  {.}/*:scalacOptions
[info]  */compile:console::scalacOptions
[info]  */compile:scalacOptions
[info]  */*:console::scalacOptions
[info]  */*:scalacOptions
[info] Related:
[info]  *:console::scalacOptions
[info]  compile:scalacOptions
[info]  *:scalacOptions
[info]  */*:scalacOptions
[info]  test:scalacOptions
```

Note: `compile:console::scalacOptions` is

- provided by `compile:scalacOptions`
- doesn't reach `*:console::scalacOptions` (which is what I defined) in the delegation chain

My question is how do I override `scalacOptions` for all configurations for console? Is it possible to change the delegation chain?

I'd like to avoid having to set `scalacOptions in (Compile, console)` (as it would be duplicated for `(Test, console)`) or define a val of scalac options.

Comment: See also https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover/issues/131

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> My question is how do I override `scalacOptions` for all configurations for console?

I don't think we can given the presence of `compile:scalacOptions` provided by sbt's `Defaults`. The only scope that has higher precedence is `compile:console::scalacOptions`.
In most cases one would not want `Compile` and `Test` settings to cross wire, so configuration scoping higher precedence I don't think is a bad default.

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
  scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-unused-import",
  scalacOptions in (Compile, console) ~= (_ filterNot (_ == "-Ywarn-unused-import")),
  scalacOptions in (Test, console) := (scalacOptions in (Compile, console)).value
)
```

> Is it possible to change the delegation chain?

No, this is not possible.
There's a single instance of `delegates` function in [BuildStructure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.BuildStructure), and it's initialized at the loading time and used for all tasks.
The ordering is done in [Scope.delegates](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.7/main/settings/src/main/scala/sbt/Scope.scala#L161-L174).

Comment: Thank you for your response Eugene, particular the details/links to the innards is very valuable to me. I guess there was a design decision made to have the default search in configuration before task (`compile:scalacOptions` before `*:console::scalacOptions`).

Comment: Is there a way to get something along these lines to work? `ivyConfigurations.value.map(c => scalacOptions in (c, console) := consoleCompilerOptions)` (It doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

I fix the bad scalac options in an autoplugin:

```
package console

import sbt._

/** [[FixScalacOptionsInConsole]] is an [[AutoPlugin]] that removes
  * noisy or unnecessary scalac options when running an sbt console.
  */
object FixScalacOptionsInConsole extends AutoPlugin {

  import Keys._

  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    Compile / console / scalacOptions ~= filter,
    Test / console / scalacOptions ~= filter
  )

  def filter: Seq[String] => Seq[String] =
    _ .filterNot(_ == "-feature")
      .filterNot(_.startsWith("-opt:"))
      .filterNot(_ == "-unchecked")
      .filterNot(_.startsWith("-Xlint:"))
      .filterNot(_ == "-Xfatal-warnings")
      .filterNot(_.startsWith("-Ywarn"))
}
```

Comment: Good idea!

Though I'd enable all features, rather than filter it out.

Comment: The plugin filters out annoying warnings, including those normally generated by `-feature`. When I'm in the console, I want to use any language feature, not just those that have been added to the base project. Could easily change this, though by adding an override list that is appended after the filter.  The point here is that you can invisibly fix this wart in sbt without hacking project definitions.

Comment: You're right.  I meant `-language:_`.  This plugin looks really useful to have, you should publish it :)