# How do I override scalacOptions for console?

Tags: scala, sbt

Overriding `scalacOptions` for the SBT console does not work for me, based on the discussion at: [In sbt, how do you override scalacOptions for console in all configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940253/in-sbt-how-do-you-override-scalacoptions-for-console-in-all-configurations)

The contents of my `build.sbt` are as follows:

```
    lazy val commonScalacOptions = Seq(
      "-deprecation",
      "-encoding", "UTF-8",
      "-feature",
      "-unchecked",
      "-Xfatal-warnings",
      "-Xlint:-missing-interpolator,_",
      "-Yinline-warnings",
      "-Yno-adapted-args",
      "-Ywarn-dead-code",
      "-Ywarn-numeric-widen",
      "-Ywarn-value-discard",
      "-Ywarn-unused-import",
      "-language:existentials",
      "-language:experimental.macros",
      "-language:implicitConversions",
      "-language:higherKinds",
      "-Xfuture")

    lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
      scalaVersion := "2.11.11",
      scalacOptions ++= commonScalacOptions,
      scalacOptions in (Compile, console)  := (scalacOptions in (Compile, console)).value filterNot ("-Ywarn-unused-import" == _),
      scalacOptions in (Test, console)     := (scalacOptions in (Compile, console)).value)

    lazy val root = Project("brontosaurus-rex", file("." + "brontosaurus-rex")).in(file("."))
      .settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

and when I run an SBT session, I can see that the `-Ywarn-unused-imports` option is not part of `compile:console::scalacOptions`

```
    > show compile:console::scalacOptions
    [info] * -deprecation
    [info] * -encoding
    [info] * UTF-8
    [info] * -feature
    [info] * -unchecked
    [info] * -Xfatal-warnings
    [info] * -Xlint:-missing-interpolator,_
    [info] * -Yinline-warnings
    [info] * -Yno-adapted-args
    [info] * -Ywarn-dead-code
    [info] * -Ywarn-numeric-widen
    [info] * -Ywarn-value-discard
    [info] * -language:existentials
    [info] * -language:experimental.macros
    [info] * -language:implicitConversions
    [info] * -language:higherKinds
    [info] * -Xfuture
```

However, attempting to run `console` with an unused import in one of my source code files, results in the unexpected error:

```
    > console
    [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to [PROJECT_DIR]/brontosaurus-rex/target/scala-2.11/classes...
    [error] [PROJECT_DIR]/brontosaurus-rex/src/main/scala/com/dinosaurs/BrontosaurusRex.scala:3: Unused import
    [error] import scala.util.matching.Regex
    [error]                            ^
    [error] one error found
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
    [error] Total time: 0 s, completed May 21, 2017 7:45:53 PM
```

It seems that the error is coming from `compile:compileIncremental`. When I show the contents of `compile:compileIncremental::scalacOptions` I see the option that I'm trying to filter out:

```
    > show compile:compileIncremental::scalacOptions
    [info] * -deprecation
    [info] * -encoding
    [info] * UTF-8
    [info] * -feature
    [info] * -unchecked
    [info] * -Xfatal-warnings
    [info] * -Xlint:-missing-interpolator,_
    [info] * -Yinline-warnings
    [info] * -Yno-adapted-args
    [info] * -Ywarn-dead-code
    [info] * -Ywarn-numeric-widen
    [info] * -Ywarn-value-discard
    [info] * -Ywarn-unused-import
    [info] * -language:existentials
    [info] * -language:experimental.macros
    [info] * -language:implicitConversions
    [info] * -language:higherKinds
    [info] * -Xfuture
```

Now, if I inspect the above, it appears to be provided by `compile:scalacOptions`. What I'm confused about is why the compiler options in `compile:console::scalacOptions` don't appear to be used when running the `console` command.

I'd like to be able to run a less strict set of compiler options for `console` and this way of doing it seems fairly straightforward. However, I'm stumped as to why the existing solution no longer works. Can anyone help set me straight here?

Answer (score 0):

First, `scalacOptions in (Compile, console)` it means setting `scalacOptions` to compile **scala** that you input in the **Console**.

As the your **compile error**, this is caused by before you go to the **Scala console**, the compiler will firstly try to compile **current project** and since you have setted `scalacOptions` for **compile**, so this **error** has throwed.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification! So, since `console` invokes the standard `compile:scalacOptions` there is no way to have them be different from what is used when calling `compile` directly.

I think what I'd want in that case is a lighter weight `risky:compile` or some such thing, so that `risky:console` will start up a console session with less strict compiler options than `console`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my side in SBT 1.3.2:

```
  val unusedImports = "-Ywarn-unused:imports"
  ...
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    unusedImports,
    "-Yrangepos",
    "-Ywarn-unused:privates"
  ),
  Compile / console / scalacOptions := (Compile / scalacOptions).value filterNot (_ eq unusedImports)
```