# Conditional scalacSettings / settingKey

Tags: sbt

I want my `scalacSettings` to be more strict (more linting) when I issue my own command `validate`.

What is the best way to achieve that?

A new scope (`strict`) did work, but it requires to compile the project two times when you issue `test`. So that's not a option.

Comment: Did you try something like this `scalacSettings in validate ++= Seq(...)`?

Comment: Does this info help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940253/in-sbt-how-do-you-override-scalacoptions-for-console-in-all-configurations?

Comment: `validate` is not a scope, but a command alias:

private def cmdAlias(name: String, commands: List[String]) =
    addCommandAlias(name, s";${commands.mkString(";")}")

cmdAlias("validateCoverage", scalafmtCheckAlias ++ coverageAlias)

Comment: Not sure about aliases in the way you use it. Can you convert `validate` into a `task` and try?

Comment: `validate` is being used when we run a build in CI and should lint strictly. While developing the compile settings are less restrictive and therefore not intrusive. I don't want to be bothered with unused imports compile errors while developing a new feature :-)

Comment: You can define values in the scope of tasks. Check out the link i posted

Comment: Very cool. However this seems not be doing what I was hoping (`strictCompile` is a `TaskKey[Unit]`):

strictCompile := (compile in Compile).value,
scalacOptions.in(Compile, compile) := baseScalacSettings,
scalacOptions.in(Compile, strictCompile) := baseScalacSettings ++ strictScalacSettings

Comment: It compiles, but with only with the baseScalacSettings

Answer (score 1):

SBT custom [command](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Commands.html) allows for temporary modification of build state which can be discarded after command finishes:

```
def validate: Command = Command.command("validate") { state =>
  import Project._
  val stateWithStrictScalacSettings =
    extract(state).appendWithSession(
      Seq(Compile / scalacOptions ++= Seq(
        "-Ywarn-unused:imports",
        "-Xfatal-warnings",
        "...",
      ))
      ,state
    )

  val (s, _) = extract(stateWithStrictScalacSettings).runTask(Test / test, stateWithStrictScalacSettings)
  s
}

commands ++= Seq(validate)
```

or more succinctly using [`::`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/f14bc7a503dda817adf0668d58b86c2d50a1f0f3/main-command/src/main/scala/sbt/State.scala#L94) convenience method for `State` transformations:

```
commands += Command.command("validate") { state =>
  """set scalacOptions in Compile := Seq("-Ywarn-unused:imports", "-Xfatal-warnings", "...")""" :: 
  "test" :: state
}
```

This way we can use `sbt test` during development, while our CI hooks into `sbt validate` which uses `stateWithStrictScalacSettings`.

Comment: I want a strict variant of compile I got this far:
  def strictCompile: Command = Command.command("strictCompile") { state =>
    val extracted = Project.extract(state)
    val ref = extracted.get(thisProjectRef)
    val s = extracted.appendWithoutSession(Seq(Compile / scalacOptions := baseScalacSettings ++ strictScalacSettings),state)
    Project.extract(s).runAggregated(Compile / compile in ref, s)
    s
  }

This is an implementation which uses runAggregated (for multiple submodules). It compiles, but it does not apply the strict compilation settings

Comment: Set the project axis to [`ThisBuild`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+the+subproject+axis) like so: `extracted.appendWithoutSession(Seq(ThisBuild / Compile / scalacOptions := baseScalacSettings ++ strictScalacSettings),state)`

Comment: I see, smart. It doesn't work when you use it inside `projectSettings` inside a `AutoPlugin` (SBT 1.x)

Comment: Is there a way to debug what's going on? `sbt inspect strictCompile` show it's a command, but doesn't show what's doing. I also use `sbt clean debug strictCompile` and it applies the `baseScalacOptions` (as it's defined in `projectSettings`), but the `strictScalacOptions` are still left out.